# Multiple tab render in parallel in WPF, C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

Assume that I have 3 different tab items with browsers and i want all the tab to load and render at the same time once I open my window application.

My question: Is there any approach for every tabs that can render in parallel or thread?

Comment: The very idea of a TabControl is that only 1 Tab renders at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack it using a custom template that uses a `ListBox` instead of the default `ContentPresenter`:

```
   <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="A">
            <WebBrowser Source="http://www.google.com/" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="B">
            <WebBrowser Source="http://www.bing.com/" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="C">
            <WebBrowser Source="http://www.yahoo.com/" />
        </TabItem>
        <Control.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TabPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                              DockPanel.Dock="{TemplateBinding TabStripPlacement}" />
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Items}"
                             SelectedIndex="{TemplateBinding SelectedIndex}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"
                                                              ContentTemplate="{Binding ContentTemplate}"
                                                              ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding ContentTemplateSelector}" />
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                        Value="Hidden" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                             Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListBox>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Control.Template>
    </TabControl>
```

Note that rendering still occurs on one thread, but because of the nature of the `WebBrowser` control, the pages are loaded in the background.

Answer (score 0):

A Window can start in its own separate UI thread. But tabs will be rendered on the UI thread the current Window is started on.